# upper and lower limit of $f'$ exists, prove that they exist for $f$ as well

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in C^1(\left[-1,1 \right]\setminus 0)$ such that the two limits
$$
\lim_{h_{>0} \rightarrow 0} f('h)=L_1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h_{<0} \rightarrow 0} f('h)=L_2
$$
exist. Prove that the limits
$$
\lim_{h_{>0} \rightarrow 0} f(h)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h_{<0} \rightarrow 0} f(h)
$$
exist as well.
Unfortunately, I am stuck. I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose that the right-hand limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$
does not exist in $[-\infty,\infty]$. Then there exist $c<d$ and
sequences $(x_{n})$, $(y_{n})$ such that:

(i) $x_{n}>0$, $y_{n}>0$,

(ii) $x_{n}\rightarrow0$, $y_{n}\rightarrow0$, and

(iii) $f(x_{n})<c<d<f(y_{n})$ for each $n$.

(For, recall that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$ does not exist in $[-\infty,\infty]\Rightarrow\liminf_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)<\limsup_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$,
from which we can choose $c<d$ such that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)<c<d<\limsup_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$. Then further choose sequences $(x_{n})$ and  $(y_{n})$...)

By further passing to subsequences, without loss of generality, we
may assume that $x_{n+1}<y_{n+1}<x_{n}<y_{n}$ for each $n$. By mean-value
theorem, for each $n$, there exists $\xi_{n}\in(x_{n},y_{n})$ such
that $f(y_{n})-f(x_{n})=f'(\xi_{n})(y_{n}-x_{n})$. Observe that $f'(\xi_{n})\rightarrow L_{1}\in\mathbb{R}$
because $\xi_{n}\rightarrow0+$. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 & < & d-c\\
 & \leq & f(y_{n})-f(x_{n})\\
 & = & f'(\xi_{n})(y_{n}-x_{n})\\
 & \rightarrow & 0,
\end{eqnarray*}
as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which is a contradiction.

Hence, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$ exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$.
We go to show that the limit is actually a real number. Suppose the
contrary that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)=+\infty$ or $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)=-\infty$.
Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f'(x)=L_{1}\in\mathbb{R}$, there exist
$M>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq M$ whenever $x\in(0,\delta)$.
Fix $x_{0}\in(0,\delta)$. For each $x\in(0,x_{0})$, by mean-value
theorem, there exists $\eta_{x}\in(x,x_{0})$ such that $f(x_{0})-f(x)=f'(\eta_{x})(x_{0}-x)$.
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |f(x_{0})-f(x)|\\
 & = & |f'(\eta_{x})(x_{0}-x)|\\
 & \leq & Mx_{0}
\end{eqnarray*}
contradicting to $|f(x)|\rightarrow\infty$ when $x\rightarrow0+$.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function $g(x)=f'(x), 0\lt x\le 1$ and $g(0)=L_1$. Then $g(x)$ is a continous function on $[0,1]$ and hence integrable.

Then , let $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$

It is uniformly continous on $[0,1]$

Now let $\{x_n\}$ be a positive sequence converging to $0$

Then $\{G(x_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence since uniformly continous functiona maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

$|G(x_n)-G(x_m)|=|\int_{x_m}^{x_n}g(x)dx|$

$=|\int_{x_m}^{x_n}f'(x)dx|$

$=|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|$    (By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

So $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy and hence convergent.

Let $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=L$

What remains to show is that $L$ is unique for arbitary sequences

Let $\{y_n\}$ be another positive sequence converging to $0$

Then $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$  as $n\to \infty$

Then by Mean Value Theorem applied to $f(x)$ on $[x_n,y_n]$ or $[y_n,x_n]$, $\exists  a_n$ such that

$\min \{x_n,y_n\} \le a_n \le \max \{x_n,y_n\}$

and

$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=|f'(a_n)(x_n-y_n)| \quad (1)$

Since

$\min \{x_n,y_n\}\to 0$ and $\max \{x_n,y_n\}\to 0$, we have by Sandwich Theorem, $a_n \to 0$

Now $a_n \to 0 \Rightarrow f'(a_n)\to L_1$

Taking limit on $(1)$, we have

$\lim_{n\to \infty} |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=0$

Since $\lim |x_n|=0 $ iff $\lim x_n=0$ , we have

$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(y_n)$

Hence the right hand limit at $0$ uniquely exist.

The same can be done for left limit.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta_\varepsilon<\min\big(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{2L}\big)$ such that for all $0<x<\delta_\varepsilon$, $|f'(x)-L|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2L}$.

By the mean value theorem, for all $0<x<y<\delta_\varepsilon$, there is $x<c_{x,y}<y$ such that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c_{x,y})||x-y|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}|x-y|+L|x-y|<\varepsilon \delta_\varepsilon+L\delta_\varepsilon<\varepsilon$$

This shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$ exists (completeness of $\mathbb{R}$).

A similar argument for the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow0-}f(x)$.